DC breakers does polarity really matter?
To route the 25 mm2 cables there is a clear need to have + on the left and - on the right. But two of these 3 DC breakers are giving the impression that they want - on the left and + on the right. I assume it doesn't matter, but 125 A DC ain't a walk in the park so I wanted to make sure to ask here first.


Edit: I am adding here that you can see in the picture 3 breakers, two have markings +/-  but don't indicate which side is line and which side is load. Both say IEC/EN 60947-2. Does the squiggly symbol tell us which side is line and which side is load?
The third one, to the left, in green, says IEC/EN 60898-1, is rated for 800 V and 10 A, and it has no markings of polarity of any kind.
I was told that 60898-1 are just repurposed AC breakers, and maybe at 800 V 10 A it matters less than 1000 V 125 A. But the first answer linked to an experiment on YouTube where 10 A 100-something V the wrong way is causing a terrible fire.
So can we affirm that the 60898-1 are easier on the polarity because they are meant to be installed by, shall we say, more carefree personnel? By the way, I can't even find a datasheet for this TOMZN breaker on the right.
PS: From answers and comments I am getting a sense that I should do a test of disconnect under load in a safe environment. This is an interesting idea. Safe environment for me is to put everything on the outside floor, think driveway. Away from any flammable structures.
There was also one comment saying not to use any breakers. This is an interesting comment as it essentially says that using breakers that are not verified can add more risk than mitigate risk. But that question I have separated out here: What breakers or switches are really needed on this solar setup?
Here is what looks like an authoritative take on the whole question on what the symbols / markings mean on these polarized breakers: Discussion Paper on the Correct Wiring of Double Pole DC Circuit Breakers.
Here is a spin-off question based on an answer that was since deleted by its author. This is exactly the wrong way to connect this DC circuit breaker, is it not?
Here is my test in my setup: https://youtu.be/YdlKk7qEwAw

Do you need them for isolation or protection? I'd avoid them if at all possible.

These sell for ~$15 alibaba... $5 slightly used ( ;) Poles Number
2
Other attributes
Place of Origin
Zhejiang, China
Rated Voltage
1000V
Breaking Capacity
20~40kA
Brand Name
TOMZN
Model Number
TZG40-PV

@Jeroen3 do you want to elaborate? Should I make another question about whether to use breakers at all and then you can provide an answer?

Yes, it very much matters if you care about the breaker opening, the arc quenching and it not bursting into flames. Image from here

A permanent magnet is used to help quench the arc, and that makes it polarity-sensitive.
The marking are confusing IMO. Check your manufacturer's data. Here is one such information page:

Polarized breakers may be prohibited by code in some jurisdictions, not so much because they don't work safely, but because installers can be knuckleheads and not install according to instructions.
For a bonus, here is a teardown from famed Youtuber Big Clive.

With batteries, current can flow in both directions, charge and discharge. Even if the device can't normally discharge the battery, if it shorts out internally, current will reverse direction... that's a problem with polarized breakers... I used fuses instead. A good fuse + disconnect combo is NH00 blade fuses in their holder.

In my case the heavy load side is not really reversible as the charge controller to battery is one leg, and battery to inverter another leg, another breaker. However my concern is that the polarized breakers are not even telling me which side is line and which is load!

@GuntherSchadow Check the manufacturer's data. The diagram for the Altech breakers shows you can use either top or bottom connections for the source provided current flows in the direction the markings indicate ('+' is where conventional current goes 'in' and '-' is where it comes out). The symbols show you the type of breaker and something about the capacity (full capacity switching from the 'x' symbols and magnetic fast + thermal slow protection, I believe, but someone can correct me if that's wrong).

@bobflux From another answer it looks like fuses and CBs are recommended. Seems a bit risky if the CB is arcing but the current isn't high enough to blow the fuse but is high enough to immolate the breaker.

This is a fuse holder for NH00 blade fuse cartridges.

It is made in two parts: the back is mounted on the wall, and the front part with the handle holds the fuses, it is hinged so it pulls the fuses out of the sockets when it is opened. So it does double duty as a disconnector and of course fuse holder. Due to the huge pullout distance, it is safe to disconnect under load even if it arcs a little bit. That's the intended use. It'll even work as remote disconnect if you pull the handle with a string.
Similar models can easily be found online for about €50, which is what I paid. NH00 fuses are available up to 160A. Usually they are rated for AC, but some are rated both for AC and 48V DC. Two phase fuse holders are also available, which would be more convenient for your battery, but three phase is usually in stock so that's what I got. I simply did not use the middle slot.

On the fuse you can see the metal tabs which hold it in the hinged cover. The contacts are pretty serious. If you only need one fuse, you can get just the solid copper blade with tabs, so you get two pole disconnect and one pole fused.
There is a whole variety of models, some designed to be mounted on bus bars, others with screw terminals, others with bolts, so beware. I got the one with M8 bolts, since Pylontech cables come pre-crimped with M8 tubular lugs.
Total cost is much lower than a proper quality DC breaker, and it's pretty tough industrial gear.

Do you need them for isolation or protection?
I'd avoid these ones if at all possible. The brand is questionable and your application does not require them, I think, let me explain:
The equipment shown is mostly low voltage and for that class there are plenty of DC fuses available.
Victron even sells them.  (please don't get them on amazon)
And there are isolators for these kinds of application (eg: battery isolators). You don't need to combine those functions.
Though, the flamy videos online often use these for solar. Which is a high-voltage lowe current application. High DC voltage is the worst to break, and indeed most of these will instantly catch fire because a decent solar array will be able to pull an arc of an inch or more.
You application is low voltage, I suspect <48V, and high current, ~100A based on 25mm2.
This probably means it won't be as spectacular as Spehro's photos.
For reference:
Eaton sells these as PLS6-DC up to 50A C-kar. With a recommended 100A GL backup fuse.

Fuses and breakers prevent the cables from melting, not the equipment.

I will indeed make another question about whether I need them at all.

I have 144V 6.825A on the PV string. That breaker is not polarized and rated for 800 VDC 10 A. So I should trust that one fine.
The others are all at 48V and 62.5A to the inverter or 125A to the battery, but with the current setup (only one string of 3 330W panels) I can't get more than 21A charge current to the battery. The only high current will be to the inverter that could reach 125V for peek load of 6 kW, but since that would be only a momentary peek load it would not trip 62.5A breaker.
What if I disconnected the 62.5A breaker at 48VDC, how bad is the arcing problem?

I would not use those breakers at all. Quality breakers cost real money. That set of breakers you got, bought from legitimate sources and manufacturers, will be in the ballpark of at least $200 US. But they will work exactly as the datasheet specifies, and they have proper safety ratings.
The breakers you got from Alibaba are essentially e-trash, but sold brand new, because there are customers who don't know any better :(
Of course, you can set up a test regimen for those breakers to qualify them for the job yourself. It requires some know-how, instrumentation and a thermal chamber. It's not necessarily expensive since the tests would be one-off, without traceability, and everything could be put together from low-cost (but brand-name) components. Still, a lot of work to "save" on those breakers.
If you value your time and your safety from fire, $200 for a set of legitimate breakers is a bargain.
Do you have smoke detectors in the house/apartment/room where you live? Are they less than 10 years old? First things first. At least you won't die from smoke inhalation while asleep...
